# iOS Receipt Data return nil in other devices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing auto-renew subscription in my app.

When the app starts, it would call appStoreReceiptURL to get the receipt and send it to server for verify.

My situation is ...

There has 2 devices D1 and D2, sign in with same account A1.

1). Build the app to the device with Xcode, sign in same sandbox test account.
    Doing purchase in D1 first, after purchase success, open app in D2, but the appStoreReceiptURL return nil data.

2). Build the release app and upload to TestFlight, and install app to devices.
    Sign in with same TestFlight account. 
    Doing purchase in D1 first, after purchase success, open app in D2, but the appStoreReceiptURL still return nil data.

In my expectation, no matter the devices, it should return same Receipt Data if they are logging with same Apple Account.

I have no idea about that and cannot find any official documents, is my assumption is right?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The receipt file is not present in sandbox until a purchase is made. In production the receipt file will almost alway be there since it's generated upon downloading the app. You should still be able to handle cases where the receipt is missing in case the user is logged out of their iTunes account.

Once you get the appStoreReceiptURL you can verify it with Apple's `/verifyReceipt` endpoint from your server to get the latest subscription status.

Comment: So, the testflight build is as same as sandbox ? I test it via testflight and assume that testflight should be as same as App Store.

Comment: Yeah Testflight builds all run in the sandbox environment as well